# Generate XSD files in Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Is there any way (not from classes/JAXB) to create XSD schemas in Java? I can parse it with the help of some libraries ie XSOM, Jdom etc. But could not find anything to create.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate why JAXB is not an option?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any easy to use way.
I considered using dom4j (because I use it for other purposes, but any other generic xml manipulation library is equivalent) and manualy create it (1).

But then I realized I can use JAXB to generate object model of xml schema, populate it with what i wanted (turned out to be much less comfortable than I hoped for) and marshall it(2). Its via JAXB, but without creating classes for your schema, so maybe it can be usefull to you.

via 2 is hard (but not impossible) to create invalid schema, but its sometimes hard to find out how to create schema I wanted. So I ended creating it in editor, then unmarshalling it and exploring its object representation. In the end, creating it via 1) and then validating it (which I had to do anyway) would be less chore.

Comment: The OP says he doesn't want to use `JAXB` in his `XSD` file generation.

Comment: It looks like he MAYBE does not want to create classes for his document and from them generate schema. But maybe he don't want to use JAXB at all, only he knows.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at apache xerces
http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/xml-schema.html

still there's no out of the box solution to handle xsd files

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Eclipse [XSD project](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=xsd#xsd), part of the Eclipse Model Development Tools. It provides a data model and API for programatically creating schemas.

Answer (score 0):

To create `XSD` is to use `java` classes/coding (is inevitable):

Just use `Java` `DOM` and create a `document` then the main `node` and create other `nodes` to attach to it and voila!